# Error creating Paypal sandbox buyer/seller accounts

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox

I am struggling to get a PayPal Sandbox up and running.

I am following the [PayPal tutorial](https://www.paypal-knowledge.com/infocenter/index?page=content&id=FAQ1408&expand=true&locale=en_US)

Every time that I create an account, in both personal and business modes, the status is error and the profile notification says

> Your sandbox account could not be created. Delete it and try again.

This even happens for the standard buyer/seller account which the Sandbox website creates when you register on the site.

Has anyone experienced something similar?

Answer (score 3):

I am also just now working on setting up paypal integration.  The developer portal's create account is just flat out broken is all i can conclude.  go to sandbox.paypal.com and create an account, then in your developer portal under accounts instead of clicking create account, underneath it, their should be some text with a link in it to link a sandbox account by logging into it, click that.  now that it's linked to your developer account you can duplicate the account to add funds to it.

Good luck getting it verified though, as i'm struggling to figure out how to actually link a bank account.  Hopefully this gets you started.